# Is it possible for a sequence of real numbers to have an imaginary limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Today I learned that it is possible for a sequence $(a_n)_n \in \mathbb Q$ to have a non rational limit: $\lim _n a_n \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$. And this motivated the following question:

> Is it possible for a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_n \in \mathbb R$ to have an imaginary limit? this is $\lim_n a_n \in \mathbb C \setminus  \mathbb R$

Or even more generally:

> If $A \subset B$, is it possible for a sequence $(a_n)_n \in A$ to have the following property: $\lim_n a_n \in B \setminus A$?

Comment: It depends on whether A is a closed set or not.

Comment: If the set is closed in $(B,\tau)$? @MartinR

Comment: if the limit of a real sequence exists, it should be real by completeness, right?

Comment: Your first line is exactly answering your second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have a (strictly) imaginary limit. This is because by definition a complex number is of the form $x+yi$, and if you write $a_n=x_n+iy_n$, and assume that $(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow (x,y)$, then since $y_n=0$, it's not possible for $y\neq 0$, as that would require $y_n\neq 0$ infinitely many times.

For your second question, it's easily possible whenever $A$ is not a closed set. For example $A=(0,1)$, $B=[0,1]$ and $a_n=1/n$.

To connect the two paragraphs, note that if $a_n$ is strictly real, then $(x_n,y_n)\in \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$, where the right side is a product of closed sets, so it's not possible to "escape" them with any convergent sequence $a_n$.

The closest analogy to rationals and irrationals here would actually be that if $a_n=x_n+y_ni$, a strictly complex number $(y_n\neq 0)$, then the limit of $a_n$ can be strictly real, e.g. $a_n=1+(1/n) i \rightarrow 1\in \mathbb{R}$. This is because $\mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

This question is referring to the mathematical notation of *completeness*. A set $A$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in the set, which is essentially what you’re asking.

$\mathbb{R}$ is complete, so every convergent sequence in it converges to a real number. That is, the answer to your first question is negative.

For the second question, this is asking precisely whether the set $A$ is complete. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, as the other answer said every closed set of a complete space is complete, so it would be completely. However the study of completeness is much richer than just this and I encourage you to learn more.